# How can I list the available color names?

Tags: terminal, colors

I'm trying to add some color to my git configuration and I want to know what color names are available on the terminal.

- I only want to use colors by name so it's easier for others to understand
- I don't want to add any new colors - I just want to select from the predefined names
- I would like a solution that works for all distros, but primarily Debian
- It would be nice to see the color that the name indicates

Many [online references](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/colors.html) often talk about color names that are not defined on my system, so I just need a way to see what my default options are.

Comment: This was a useful reference.  I like the shell scripts. http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting#terminals_compatibility

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Many online references often talk about color names that are not defined on my system

Those probably are defined, but they are X11 colors; once upon a time you could find them in `/lib[64]/X11/rgb.txt`.  In any case, this is a mapping of strings (e.g., `dimgray`) to 24-bit RGB colors (e.g. `0xff8800` or `#ff8800`, which would be orange).  A 24-bit space is ~16 million colors, obviously X11 does not give them all names (CSS 3 uses X11 names, BTW).

The 24-bit space is used by your GUI; transparency is implemented by increasing this to a 32-bit space.  **However, `git` isn't a GUI (G = graphical) tool,** it's a TUI (T = terminal) tool, and it is limited to the colors available on a normal terminal.

> I would like a solution that works for all distros, but primarily Debian

If you want this to be properly portable, you should rely only on [the eight standard ANSI colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_color#Colors):

- black
- blue
- green
- yellow
- cyan
- white
- magenta
- red

A little disappointing next to the X11 list, but better than nothing at all!  These also have a "bold" or "bright" version that is standard, making 16 colors, which you *may* be able to specify as, e.g., "brightyellow" (*or* conversely, "darkyellow").

Most GUI terminals<sup>1</sup> have 256 color support and some terminal apps can exploit this.  To test, you first need to set the `$TERM` variable appropriately:

```
export $TERM=xterm-256color
```

Your terminal emulator may also have a configuration option for this.  Colors under the [xterm 256 color protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm#Protocols) are indexed:

[image: xterm color chart]

The index number is in the bottom left corner.  Notice the set at the bottom of this chart (0-15) is the 16 basic (bright and dark) ANSI colors.  To reference one of these colors under the standard, you use `color` + the index number, eg. `color40`.

---

<sup>1. A "GUI terminal" is a terminal emulator that runs in a GUI context, such as xterm, the GNOME terminal, etc.  However, this does not make TUI apps (such as git) running in a GUI terminal into GUI apps.  *They are still TUI apps and are bound by that context.*</sup>

Comment: Sorry, the X11 list may have been misleading.  I am not interested in any kind of GUI - just colors available on the terminal.

Comment: Well, there you have it.  Presuming normal hardware, any terminal you encounter on linux has 16 colors, the eight above each with a "bright/bold" version as per the ANSI standard (although, e.g., usually only the bright yellow looks yellow; the normal one looks ochre, etc).  So WRT to git, you can use those 8.  My point was you can't use just any color you see on the screen.  **The terminal interface is a limitation.**  Eight basic colors.  That's all.

Comment: @doub1ejack : Guess what?  I noticed yesterday that **there is a standard for naming colors on 256-color terminals,** and there are some TUI apps that use it, although I did not check git.  Anyway, I've edited some stuff in about this.

Comment: I think there are only 8 colors and 8 bright versions. Saying they are 16 colors is not technically correct?

Comment: @jiggunjer What's your point?  I am very clear and explicit about this ('you should rely only on the eight standard ANSI colors... These also have a "bold" or "bright" version that is standard, making 16 colors...').  I also repeat "Eight basic colors. That's all" in a comment above.

Comment: Yes it is clear. I just see conflicting information on the web and wanted to confirm. I was wondering what the other 8 colors were when I realized it was just the bold versions, and I wasn't missing colors :p.

Comment: Yeah "16 colors" is a bit misleading until you read the fine print ;) I'd guess the reason for this is arbitrary in that it's about maintaining backward compatibility with [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) stuff, but I don't know.

Comment: I was reading this answer, waiting until I got to the how. I was nearly there, and the answer stopped.

Answer (score -2):

In CentOS you have showrgb:

showrgb - display an rgb color-name database

Comment: `showrgb` lists X colours, not terminal colours which is what is needed here.