# Output colored text in all major distros without using non-word color codes (like \033[0;31m)

Tags: bash, colors, output, distributions, stability

I found these ways, for example, to output colored text in a simple way to the screen:

```
RED="\033[0;31m" # Red color (via ANSI escape code);
NC='\033[0m' # No color (via ANSI escape code);
echo -e "${RED}This text is red. ${NC}" # -e flag allows backslash escapes;
```

or:

```
printf '\e[1;34m%-6s\e[m' "This is blue text"
```

I also found:

```
tput setaf 1; echo "this is red text"
```

But I never used `tput` and I'm not sure it's shipped with all major distros (Debian, CetnOS, Arch, and so forth).

### My question

How to output colored text in a given named, common color (like "Red") in a simple way I could count on to work on all major distros, without using "messy" color codes?

Comment: I think the ANSI escape sequences (used for your RED and NC variables) work in most major linux distros. I have tested in several distros (and found that they work).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I list the available color names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105568/how-can-i-list-the-available-color-names)

Comment: @ThomasDickey I miss why it is a duplicate; I don't want to list anything... Just using some global (distro-agnostic) simple command with simply-named color...

Comment: The linked duplicate is different.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the answer seems more complete than yours here and answers fully this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Codes (ANSI colour codes)

The codes are not distro dependent. They are terminal dependent. Some terminals will not support them. However they are probably supported by most.

## Names

Use variables to give names e.g.

```
red="$(tput setaf 1)"
echo "${red}hello"
```

note: don't use capitals for shell variables, capitals should be reserved for environment variables.

## Names and codes

The codes refer to a colour number. the colour for each number is defined by the terminal, and in non-standard. The user can change it.

Comment: Hi ! By "codes" on the very start, you meant ANSI escape-codes, right?

Answer (score 8):

## You can use `tput`.

> I'm not sure [that `tput` is] shipped with all major distros

It's part of ncurses, and packaged with it on all three of those operating systems and more.

- [Debian list of files in the ncurses-bin package on `stable`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/arm64/ncurses-bin/filelist)
- [Arch list of files in the ncurses package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/ncurses/files/)
- [Fedora description for ncurses package](https://src.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/ncurses.git/tree/ncurses.spec#n25)
- [FreeBSD list of files in the ncurses port/package](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/devel/ncurses/pkg-plist?view=markup#l5)
- [It's actually part of base on OpenBSD](https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/usr.bin/tput).

So `tput setaf` will work across a broad range of systems, with the obvious proviso that the requisite package needs to be installed.

The downside is that using it still ends up employing "non-word colour codes", as the numbers that one supplies are the 8 standard colours indices from ECMA-48 (with a possible extra 8 de facto standard colours on some terminal emulators, and up to 256 colours by using ISO 8613-6 Indexed colour on some).

On the gripping hand, the 8 standard ECMA-48 colours are well known, and what (for example) "6" means as a colour number is not all that obscure.

## You can also use `setterm`.

However, if you are looking for more human-readable commands that use names rather than numbers, albeit in English only, there are widespread tools that can do that, too.  One such is `setterm`, which is used like this:

```
% setterm --foreground red ; echo "this is red text"
```

The `setterm` that you will find in the repositories of Debian, Fedora, and Arch is the one from the util-linux toolset.  That command relies upon various Linux-specific things for some of the *other* actions that the command can perform, and it of course is not available on the BSDs.  The toolset *is* Linux-specific and not portable, as its name tells one.

Also, whilst its manual page claims that the terminfo database is consulted, changing colours is one of quite a few cases where the actual program does not work as documented.  It *does not* consult the `setaf` and `setab` capabilities in terminfo.  Rather, the program hardwires the ECMA-48 SGR 30–37,39,40–47,49 control sequences.

Moreover, it does not support the additional 8 de facto standard colour indices from 8 to 15.  It hasn't been kept up to date with the capabilities of the Linux KVT, which does support the "bright" colours, and which nowadays at least *accepts* ISO 8613-6 Indexed and Direct colour control sequences (albeit that it does not actually implement full 24-bit colour).

Furthermore, [because of a bug in that very hardwiring code, the version of util-linux `setterm` in Debian Stable does not emit the right SGR sequences when setting colours](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917100#5).

- [`setterm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setterm.1.html). *User Commands*.  Michael Kerrisk. 2014-05.

### … even on the BSDs, now.

Finding that bug was one of the things that inspired me to write a `setterm` replacement, which (coincidentally) I have just done.  I didn't copy the (moderate amount of) stuff that was idiosyncratic to Linux and to its kernel virtual terminals.  And conversely I did add some ECMA-48 stuff that has been around for several decades that the util-linux `setterm` does not have (because the Linux KVT did not support that part of ECMA-48, and `setterm` has its roots in being specific to the Linux KVT).  I also added UTF-8, support for the actual 8-bit C1 control characters (as well as their 7-bit aliases), and ISO 8613-6 Direct colour (if the terminal type is known to support it).

And of course, this implementation *does* exist for the BSDs:

```
% uname ; printenv TERM
FreeBSD
rxvt
% TERM=ansi setterm --7bit --foreground red|hexdump -C 
00000000  1b 5b 33 31 6d                                    |.[31m|
00000005
% setterm --7bit --foreground red|hexdump -C 
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 35 3b 31  6d                       |.[38;5;1m|
00000009
% setterm --7bit --foreground 192|hexdump -C 
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 35 3b 31  39 32 6d                 |.[38;5;192m|
0000000b
% setterm --7bit --foreground '#00BEC119'|hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 35 3b 31  39 31 6d                 |.[38;5;191m|
0000000b
% TERM=vte-256color setterm --7bit --foreground '#00BEC119'|hexdump -C 
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 32 3b 31  39 30 3b 32 35 3b 31 39  |.[38;2;190;25;19|
00000010  33 6d                                             |3m|
00000012
% TERM=ansi setterm --7bit --foreground 'bright red' --background 'bright yellow'|hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 39 31 6d 1b 5b 31  30 33 6d                 |.[91m.[103m|
0000000b
% setterm --7bit --foreground 'bright red' --background 'bright yellow'|hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 38 3b 35 3b 39  6d 1b 5b 34 38 3b 35 3b  |.[38;5;9m.[48;5;|
00000010  31 31 6d                                          |11m|
00000013
%
```

It is in version 1.39 of the nosh toolset, in the terminal management package with the name `console-control-sequence`, allowing one to have this side-by side with util-linux.  The `setterm` shim name for the command is provided by a separate shims package.  So if you write something using `setterm` to change colours and someone claims that that is Linux-specific, you know where to direct them.  I've put the manual page up as a preview.

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`setterm`](http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/setterm.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

## Get the SGR codes right, by the way.

SGR 0 *is not* "no colour".  SGR 0 resets all colours and attributes.  There actually is not a concept of "no" colour.  There *is* a concept of the "default" colour, set by SGR 39 and SGR 49:

```
% setterm --7bit --foreground default --background default|hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 33 39 6d 1b 5b 34  39 6d                    |.[39m.[49m|
0000000a
%
```

Comment: Looks like the original jdebp.eu site is no more and seems like [this](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/nosh/guide/setterm.html) is the page on the new site. Would I be correct in assuming that the easiest way to get your version of the `setterm` command under a Linux distro such as Fedora would be to build [nosh](http://jdebp.info/Softwares/nosh/) from the repo that you have hosted on github [here](https://github.com/synety-jdebp/nosh/tree/master/source)? Or if I only am really interested in the additional `setterm` functionality is there an easier way to just get that by itself?