# 'less -R' not working

Tags: colors, less

I got this in a file:

```
\033[31mException log
```

And when I do:

```
less -R demo
```

I get no colors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that an actual escape character (U+1B) would be represented as `ESC` in inverse colors, if you ran `less demo`, without `-R`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the actual escape code in the file. One way to do this would be:

```
echo -e "\033[31mException log\033[0m" > file.txt
```

Then `less -R file.txt` should be able to interpret the color code.

Comment: Some other ways to generate these control sequences are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491863/ .

Answer (score 1):

These characters are not a colour code sequence, but they are the sequence to tell some tools/programming-languages to create the desired character sequence.

e.g.

```
echo -e "\033[31mException log"
```

Answer (score 0):

Test that your terminal actually supports the colours by running:

```
cat your_file.txt
```

If your file has colour codes, your terminal will show them. If not, then either 1) your term isn't configured to support it or 2) you've entered incorrect codes.